# Query client evaluations in Entity Framework Identity

Tags: entity-framework, azure-cosmosdb, identity, asp.net-core-identity, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

In my Asp .Net Core 3.1 app I'm using EF Core Identity to handle users authentication. As a database provider i use CosmosDB with SQL API.

Creating user with `userManager.CreateAsync(...)` goes smooth. I see new user data in database.
But when I'm trying to sign in with these credentials using `signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(...)` I get exception:

```
InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<IdentityUserRole<string>>
.Join(
outer: DbSet<IdentityRole>,
inner: i => i.RoleId,
outerKeySelector: i0 => i0.Id,
innerKeySelector: (i, i0) => new TransparentIdentifier<IdentityUserRole<string>, IdentityRole>(
Outer = i,
Inner = i0
))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Linked microsoft document says that this query has to be evaluated on client. So my question is, how can i change query for IdentityRole to achievie that?

Im using default Identity entities - IdentityUser and IdentityRole

Sign up code:

```
    public class DashboardController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;

        public DashboardController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(string username, string password)
        {
            var user = new IdentityUser
            {
                UserName = username,
                Id = username,
            };

            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                //sign in
                var signInResult = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, password, false, false);
                // here I also tried to use method with different signature (username, password, ...)

                if (signInResult.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SignIn(string username, string password)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);

            if (user != null)
            {
                var signInResult = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, password, false, false);

                if (signInResult.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("SignIn");
        }
        .
        .
        .
   }
```

Comment: your code is not complete,Insert more of your code,I think you didn't execute your query,get User entity first and then send it to `PasswordSignInAsync` method .So your code should be like => `context.User.where(e=>e.Id=="1").First();` for example

Comment: @mohsen My sign up post action code added above

Comment: you have not saved the user roles ,first save the role and then in register method add user to role `UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(NewUser, "Admin");` then add claims if needed , and then signin

Comment: Just because there _is_ an EF provider for Cosmos DB, doesn't mean you can use it for all existing EF applications.  Cosmos DB has a different SQL dialect, and may not be able to execute all the query shapes that SQL Server can.  You'd need to modify the code of `PasswordSignInAsync` to force client-side evaluation to make this work.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Probably you are right. The issue is CosmosDB itself. I changed provider to AzureSQL and now it works.
I don't want to mess with Identity lib and AzureSQL is also good for me so I will just stick with this solution. Thanks!